# D3.js transition only works for the deleted Elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I update my data source, the transition only works for the deleted elements, but not for the updated elements.

I have inserted a `.transition()` in the "deleted section" and in the "update section". I suspect that the `transition()` function in my update section is being used incorrectly.

No error is displayed, which could help me to solve the problem.

Can someone please help me?

```js
            // Data
            const data1 = {
            "name": "TOPICS",
            "id": 1,
            "children": [{
                "name": "Topic A",
                "id": 2,
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Sub A1",
                    "id": 5,
                    "size": 4
                    }, {
                    "name": "Sub A2",
                    "id": 6,
                    "size": 4
                    }]
            }, {
                "name": "Topic B",
                "id": 3,
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Sub B1",
                    "id": 7,
                    "size": 3
                    }, {
                    "name": "Sub B2",
                    "id": 8,
                    "size": 3
                    }, {
                    "name": "Sub B3",
                    "id": 9,
                    "size": 3
                    }]
            }, {
                "name": "Topic C",
                "id": 4,
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Sub A3",
                    "id": 10,
                    "size": 4
                    }, {
                    "name": "Sub A4",
                    "id": 11,
                    "size": 4
                    }]
            }]
            };

            const data2 = {
            "name": "TOPICS",
            "id": 1,
            "children": [{
                "name": "Topic A",
                "id": 2,
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Sub A1",
                    "id": 5,
                    "size": 4
                    }, {
                    "name": "Sub A2",
                    "id": 6,
                    "size": 4
                    }]
            }, {
                "name": "Topic B",
                "id": 3,
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Sub B1",
                    "id": 7,
                    "size": 3
                    }, {
                    "name": "Sub B2",
                    "id": 8,
                    "size": 3
                    }, {
                    "name": "Sub B3",
                    "id": 9,
                    "size": 3
                    }]
            }]
            };

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
            // Declare variables
            let i_region_static_id = "sunburst",
                parentDiv = document.getElementById(i_region_static_id),
                width = parentDiv.clientWidth,
                height = 450,
                root,
                x,
                y,
                color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
                maxRadius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 5;


            const partition = d3.partition();
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // SVG-Element
            let svg = d3.select('#' + i_region_static_id).append('svg')
                            .style('width', width)
                            .style('height', height)
                            .attr('viewBox', `${-width / 2} ${-height / 2} ${width} ${height}`)

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // X-Scale
            x = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
                    .clamp(true);

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Y-Scale
            y = d3.scaleSqrt()
                    .range([maxRadius * .1, maxRadius]);

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Create Arc generator
            const arc = d3.arc()
                .startAngle(d => x(d.x0))
                .endAngle(d => x(d.x1))
                .innerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y0)))
                .outerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y1)))

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Initialize and Update sun 
            function update_sun(pData) {
                const valueAccessor = (d) => d.size;

                root = d3.hierarchy(pData); //set data
                
                valueAccessor == null ? root.count() : root.sum((d) => Math.max(0, valueAccessor(d)));

                // Sort Nodes
                root.sort((d) => d3.descending(d.value))

                const slice = svg.selectAll('g.slice')
                    .data(
                        partition(root).descendants(),
                        function(d) { return d.data.id; }
                    );

                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------             

                // Update Section
                const newSlice = slice.enter() //rect_node_grp
                                    .append('g').attr('class', 'slice')
                                    .attr('display', d => d.depth < 2 ? null : 'none') // Hide levels lower depth
                                    .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
                                    .each(function(d) {
                                            //Append Elemente an g
                                                d3.select(this).append('path')   
                                                    // .attr('class', 'main-arc')
                                                    .style('fill', d => (d.data.color == undefined) ? color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name) : d.data.color) //set source color, otherwise default color
                                                    // .attr('d', arc); 
                                            })
                                    .merge(slice)
                                    .each(function(d) {
                                                // Update meine Elemente in g tag
                                                d3.select(this).select('path')
                                                .attr('class', 'main-arc')
                                                    .transition()
                                                    .delay(100)
                                                    .attr('d', arc);  
                                                    // .attrTween("d", arcTween)
                                        })
       
                // Delete Section
                slice.exit().transition().duration(500).style("fill-opacity", 0.2).remove();
            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            update_sun(data1)

            let i = 0;
            d3.interval(() => {
            if (i++ % 2 === 0) {
                console.log("data2")
                update_sun(data2);
            } else {
                console.log("data1")
                update_sun(data1);
            }

            }, 4000)
```

```css
.slice .main-arc {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>             
    <head>              
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sun.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>             
        <div id="sunburst"></div>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want `slice.selectAll('path')` instead of `slice.select('path')`?

Comment: Yes sorry, slice.selectAll('path') instead of slice.select('path'). But if I use slice.selectAll('path'), the existing slices are not adjusted. Do you know why?

Comment: What's up with the nested functions in the tween?

Comment: If I do not use the .arctween() function I get the following error for the transition of the arc "<path> attribute d: Expected arc flag ('0' or '1')". From existing entries of stackoverflow[1] I have taken that I have to use .arctween() for the transition function. [1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356095/error-when-transitioning-an-arc-path-attribute-d-expected-arc-flag-0-or